# What does the j function in Rails do?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I just came across a blog that mentions a `j` function in Rails.  They were using it to do ajax style page updates.

```
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
```

I get they are using partials to render the `cart` partial, but whats the point of `j`? I've found some articles that say it converts the string to something JavaScript will accept, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> **`escape_javascript(javascript)`**
>
> Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.
>
> Also available through the alias j().

From the [the rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html).

Answer (score 84):

Peter actually posted the correct answer. But I will try to elaborate:

I guess you are familiar with the basic concept of ajax? 
Lets say you want to be able to create comments in an ajaxy fashion.
In rails you may respond to *POST* requests in your `CommentsController` via:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  respond_to do |format|
    render.js
  end
end
```

This means if an ajax request from the client (via jquery/javascript) is submitted to the **`CommentsController`** it will recognize the format (`.js`) and respond with the **_create.js.erb** partial.
The partial would then render the new comment with something like this:

```
$('.comments').append("<%=j render @comment %>");
```

**Now to get to the j or escape_javascript method:**
Some *evil* user may submit a comment containing (malicious) javascript which would be executed on your page **unless** you make use of the `j` method which

> Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.

and therefore prevents the execution of the code in the browser.

Comment: Note that even if what you're rendering isn't user created, you probably still want to escape characters that aren't javascript safe because otherwise your javascript may break.